# How create car emblem from STL file?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a interesting (for me) task - make a car emblem for some auto club. 
Client asked me create emblem (flat, vectorized) and make some changes.

I'm done and now he would get STL file for print. 
I created svg, then convert to STL and... stuck ( 
[image: This part of emblem, chrome borders and red inside]

My problem is — in creating borders and depth. I'm graphic designer, working in Illustrator and Photoshop, but i don't know how can i realise this task. Please help me - give some advise, please.

Thank you.

Here SVG file: [link](https://yadi.sk/d/VJbeK3m2BSESsA)

Comment: Hellow and welcome. We have [quite a lot of questions covering this already](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=svg), how do they fail to cover your case?

Comment: @Pavel Is [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGV3rGtqEec) helpful to you? He imports a .svg into Blender and extrudes the faces to create depth. Perhaps you could share your .svg and I can see what it capable of it.

Comment: Sorry for late. Thank you. Here is svg file: [link](https://yadi.sk/d/VJbeK3m2BSESsA) 
In that file black stroke (border) need to be 2 cm higher than red zone.

Answer (score 1):

I have to run to class, but I'll upload a tutorial to YouTube in an hour for this. If you need it now, here is a test file where I extruded the S.

Basically, I imported the .svg into blender and converted it (Alt + c) to a mesh. Then I extruded the meshes. I used a boolean modifier to delete/hollow out the middle of the S.

Here is a [screencast](https://youtu.be/-BbTjtrIKC4) of the process. I will upload a more comprehensive video later if needed.

[image]

Comment: If you can - it realy helping for me. Sorry for my english. But i have a one more question - why .svg importing not correct? line inder "upercharged" must be full width - under "up..." and under "...ed". Maybe i not correct export ?